# Publishing restriction according to language and target

Tags: publishing

We are still using an old version (`6.6`).

We have multiple publishing targets (one is a web and the other production) and there is one specific language (Spanish 'es') item we have made publishable to web target by selecting the web target check box in the publishing section.

When we publish the Spanish item, the Spanish language gets published to web target only. But now we added the version of any item in Spanish and publish it to all targets in all languages, the item version in Spanish also gets published to all targets including production even though the Spanish language is not available on the production target, because this is restricted. I have verified this item by switching to that target database. I thought that if we don't have language in one target then the language version of the item would not be published.

Are we thinking right?

Answer (score 2):

It is an expected behavior. Sitecore uses publish targets field to determine if the item need to be published to some target, however publishing target field is shared so you can't specify publishing targets depends on language version. And you can select specific language and specific target only in Publish dialog.

You can customize publishing process, in case to add additional field to a publish target item and restrict some languages.